# flex chart columnseries not visible

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a flex chart that I'm trying to build via actionscript dynamically. For test purposes I came up with the following data structure and code:

```
Bindable]
        public var columnDat:Array= 
        [{signalID:"SCL", point2:100},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:50},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:30},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:60},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:220},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:140},
        {signalID:"SCL", point2:280}];

public function makeDummyChart(genericChart:CartesianChart, genericLegend:Legend, chartPanel:ChartPanel):void {

            var renderers:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            genericChart = new ColumnChart();

            // Define the two axes.
            var dispAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            var axr:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();              
            axr.axis = dispAxis;
            renderers.addItem(axr); 

            var seriesList:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();

            // Add the series
            genericChart.horizontalAxis = dispAxis;
            var columnSeries:ColumnSeries = new ColumnSeries();     
            BindingUtils.bindProperty(columnSeries, "dataProvider", this, "columnDat");

            columnSeries.xField="signalID";;
            columnSeries.yField="point2";
            seriesList.addItem(columnSeries);

            genericChart.series = seriesList.toArray();
            genericLegend.dataProvider = genericChart;

            genericChart.horizontalAxisRenderers = renderers.toArray();

            genericLegend.dataProvider = genericChart;
            // chart panel is just the panel on the screen where chart is displayed
            chartPanel.addChild(genericChart);
                trace ("  make dummy chart done");

        }
```

I just get a blank chart when I run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it by now, but it should be sufficient if you just assign the `columnDat` array to the series:

```
columnSeries.dataProvider = columnDat;
```

or to the column chart:

```
genericChart.dataProvider = columnDat;
```

Comment: Well columnSeries.dataProvider = columnDat; didn't work (and actually, I need to add them one by one like this in the real app so I didn't try the genericChart version).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably use MXML for this stuff.  It's easier.

Second, I don't think you followed the example very well.  There's 2 ways of doing charts:

1) Add data to the *chart* data provider and have the *series* specify the x and y field within that data provider.

2) Don't add data to the *chart* and just add the data directly into *series* without specifying the x and y field.

Right now, you're doing a mix of both 1 and 2 and the series can't see the data because it's being filtered out, which is why it's blank.  Don't set the data provider on the series, but set it on the chart instead and it should work.  For further example, [look at the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/ColumnSeries.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: Actually, I can't use mxml or I would. These charts are loaded on the fly. The real data will be read from a database (I'm just using the static array here for testing) and there will almost always be more than one series. And as for point #2 where do you see me adding data to the chart?